# Whats the best file location to download content to?

Tags: wpf

I am building a WPF application and while im not a newbie, I am not an expert either.  My WPF application streams images from a website when connected to the internet.  If a user selects the image, I would like to save it to the hard drive. The user would then reuse the image later on when loading the application if it isn't connected to the internet.  I will be querying a folder to see if its there in a saved location as well.

I question where the best location is to save it? I think it might be document settings and then application data, but Im not too sure.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I assume you want to work with the windows temp directory. Simply put, you want to achieve some form of caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For behind the scenes data i usually use the local app data, you can get the directory like this (in case you did not know):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

I create some root folder there for the application to store the data in, cleanup can then just be done by getting rid of the whole folder.